# Understanding dimension of input to pre-defined LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to design a model in tensorflow to predict next words using lstm.
[Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) tutorial for RNN gives pseudocode how to use LSTM for PTB dataset.
I reached to step of generating batches and labels.

```
def generate_batches(raw_data, batch_size):
  global data_index
  data_len = len(raw_data)
  num_batches = data_len // batch_size
  #batch = dict.fromkeys([i for i in range(num_batches)])
  #labels = dict.fromkeys([i for i in range(num_batches)])
batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.float)
labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.float)
for i in xrange(batch_size) :   
    batch[i] = raw_data[i + data_index]
    labels[i, 0] = raw_data[i + data_index + 1]
data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(raw_data)
return batch, labels
```

This code gives batch and labels size (batch_size X 1).

These batch and labels can also be size of (batch_size x vocabulary_size) using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`.

So, the problem here is how to proceed next using the function `rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell` or using user defined lstm model?
 What will be the `input dimension to LSTM cell` and how will it be used with `num_steps`?
Which size of batch and labels is useful in any scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The full example for PTB is in the source [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). There are recommended defaults (`SmallConfig`, `MediumConfig`, and `LargeConfig`) that you can use.